Non-hierarchical navigation in Flutter
In Flutter, how would I implement a navigation which is not hierarchical?
For example, say that the app is a calendar, I'm on the November page, then I tap on 30 and open the page for that day, then I swipe to the next day which is December 1st, then I tap the "back" ("up"?) button and should go to the December page. (All of this with animated transitions of course.)
I suppose that Navigator.pop() would go back to November instead of December, so is it possible to tweak the Navigator or should I use a routing package?

using normal flutter Navigator? or go_router? or just using own, custom animated widget?

@pskink This is the question. I'd prefer the easiest solution. See my edits.

if you want left / right swipes then use PageView - it could work for day level / month level or even year level (if you need it)

i mean one PageView with animated stuff inside that smoothly transitions from day view to month view

OK but how to go back to December instead of November.

you need to track the current month, keep the updated day and month when swiping, thats all

You mean everything in the same widget with no route at all? I'm not sure it's the easiest solution.

and how otherwise would you want to do nice transitions between routes? with Hero widgets?
